# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException with Windows phone 8 when tracking location

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, location, system.reflection

I'm developing an app based in GPS services and i must track the location of the user continuously, like HERE Maps, and I'm using the code bellow:

```
geolocator = new Geolocator();
geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
geolocator.MovementThreshold = 20; //Doesn't matter the value I put here, it won't work
geolocator.PositionChanged += geolocator_PositionChanged;

void geolocator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        if(args.Position != null)
        {
             myPosition = args.Position.Coordinate.ToGeoCoordinate();
             UpDateData();
        }
     });
}
```

The problem is: I got a System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Do you have any solutuon for that kind of problem ?

Comment: Make sure `ID_CAP_LOCATION` is checked in Capabilities.  If that doesn't solve your problem, I would assume it's coming from the `UpDateData()`, comment that out.

Comment: ID_CAP_LOCATION was the first thing that I checked  when I started the development part

Comment: In UpDateData() function I only put pushpins in the map control based on my current location

Comment: So what happens if you comment it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        try
        {
            geolocator = new Geolocator();
            geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
            geolocator.ReportInterval = 2000;
            geolocator.PositionChanged += geolocator_PositionChanged;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Location  is Disabled in Phone Settings.");
        }

        private void geolocator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
        {
        try
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                if (args.Position != null && args.Position.Coordinate.ToGeoCoordinate() != myPosition)
                {
                    if(args.Position.Coordinate.Accuracy <= 1500)
                    {
                        myPosition = args.Position.Coordinate.ToGeoCoordinate();
                        UpDateMyPositionCircle(args.Position.Coordinate.Accuracy);
                    }
                }
            });
        } 
        catch (TargetInvocationException tie) 
        {
            if (tie.Data == null) throw;
            else MessageBox.Show("TargetInvocationException while Tracking: " + tie.InnerException.ToString());                    
        }
        catch(SystemException se)
        {
            if (se.Data == null) throw;
            else MessageBox.Show("SystemException while Tracking: " + se.InnerException.ToString());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Data == null) throw;
            else MessageBox.Show("Exception while Tracking: " + ex.InnerException.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this error is causes by the **location** not being marked as **on** in your application manifest file

Comment: ID_CAP_LOCATION was the first thing that I checked  when I started the development part

Answer (score 0):

As @Stuart mentioned make sure that you've ticked the `ID_CAP_LOCATION` from your `AppManifest` file. If you don’t do this your app will throw an exception and when you try deploy it during development and will cause your app to fail.

[How to continuously track the phone's location for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj247548(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: ID_CAP_LOCATION was the first thing that I checked  when I started the development part